# Django channels websocket disconnects after handshake

Tags: python, django, websocket, disconnect, django-channels

I am building a simple chat room following examples of django channels. Everything worked like a charm yesterday and I managed to create a chatroom and even managed to chat in there. All of a sudden without any change in my code the Websocket started  disconnecting immediately after connection and handshake.

```
My setup:
Django == 1.10.5
Python == 2.7
channels == 1.1.8
asgi-redis == 1.4.2
daphne == 1.3.0
```

My consumers.py looks like this:

```
consumers.py:
@channel_session
def ws_connect(message):
    room = message.content['path'].strip("/")
    message.channel_session['room'] = room
    Group("chat").add(message.reply_channel)
    message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})
```

And the frontend part :

```
 $(function() {
        // When we're using HTTPS, use WSS too.
        var ws_scheme = window.location.protocol = "ws";
        var chatsock = new WebSocket(ws_scheme + '://' + window.location.host + window.location.pathname);


        chatsock.onmessage = function(message) {
            var data = JSON.parse(message.data);
            var chat = $("#chat");
            var ele = $('<tr></tr>');
            console.log(data);

            ele.append(
                $("<td></td>").text(data.timestamp)
            );
            ele.append(
                $("<td></td>").text(data.handle)
            );
            ele.append(
                $("<td></td>").text(data.message)
            );

            chat.append(ele)
        };

        $("#chatform").on("submit", function(event) {
            var time = new Date();
            var string = time.getHours() + ":" + time.getMinutes() + ":" + time.getSeconds();
            // var timestamp = time.getHourMinuteSecond();
            var message = {
                timestamp: string,
                handle: $('#handle').val(),
                message: $('#message').val()
            };
            console.log("submit");
            chatsock.send(JSON.stringify(message));
            $("#message").val('').focus();
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Maybe an update in some technology is out. I am struggling to find out why this happens. In settings.py I have the following configuration for the redis channel layer:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("localhost", 6379)],
        },
        "ROUTING": "config.routing.channel_routing",
    },
}
```

I have another websocket logic for notifications which is also disconnecting right after handshake. I tried updating Django to 1.11. but no luck. In routing.py of the chat app:

```
chat_routing = [
    route("websocket.connect", consumers.ws_connect),
    route("websocket.receive", consumers.ws_message),
    route("websocket.disconnect", consumers.ws_disconnect),
]
```

I am running on Linux Ubuntu 16.04 and the only thing I updated in the last few days is Chrome version. So any ideas what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out to be a Google Chrome update issue. probably going a version back will fix the problem if I can do it but that's the issue because I tried it on Mozilla and it still works like a charm.

Comment: Is there any word on when this will be fixed. Its been two months and I still see this behavior

Comment: As I developed my project it turned out to be a matter of localhost and chrome. I believe that if you serve your project using your IP address it will be fine - python manage.py runserver <set_ip:port>

Comment: This is useful information, can you please give some reference to how you narrowed it down?

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to @Vasil answer above, this seems to be an issue in Chrome when localhost is used as the domain name of your running django project. If you run the project with an IP instead of Localhost, Chrome will not cause any issues.

Answer (score 0):

The error can be fixed if you add a slash `+'/'` to the end of the URL:

```
var chatsock = new WebSocket(ws_scheme + '://' + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '/');
```

In most cases `/` missing at the end causes problems in Chrome browser, but works fine in Firefox